# calculation of two series

Tags: pine-script

a bit puzzle how solve the following issue.
I have two series of bool value.

now I know if there are true values within max distance / gap of 4 bars.

example I have folloiwng series

```
000000000000 1 00000000....
000000000010 0 00000000.....

or of this two will be
000000000010 1 00000000.......
```

here the gap between two 1 is 2, so how I can plot it or some indication.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `bgcolor()` or `plotchar()` to make the current value of your series visible.
Like this

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", "SO", true)

var bool    myBool = na

myBool := close > open

plotchar(myBool, "myBool", "")
bgcolor(myBool ? color.yellow : na)
```

Comment: thanks but I want to have some alert or indication when the gap between two 1 is 4 or bellow. example 000000000010 1 00000000....... gap between two 1 is 1 so I want to indicate that

Comment: Could you please update your question and add the complete script you currently have?